# How to display the user's name on a messagebox in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I want to put the name of the user after they log in and saying (for example) "Welcome Bruce"
or "Welcome Batman" something like that. how can i get the value of a specific column and display it on a messagebox?? i'm using visualt studio c# 2008 and ms sql 2005. windows form

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MJ-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Users;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE U_Name=@U_Name AND U_Pass=@U_Pass", conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@U_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@U_Pass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;

                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {




                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        dr.Read();
                        int userType = Convert.ToInt32(dr["U_Type"]);

                        if (userType == 1)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
                            MDIParent1 settingsForm = new MDIParent1();
                            settingsForm.Show();
                            this.Hide();
                        }
                        else if (userType == 2)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
                            MDIParent2 settingsForm = new MDIParent2();
                            settingsForm.Show();
                            this.Hide();
                        }
                    }


                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed");
                        Outcome = Convert.ToInt32(lblOutcome.Text);
                        Outcome = Outcome - 1;
                        textBox1.Clear();
                        textBox2.Clear();

                        lblOutcome.Text = Outcome.ToString();
                        if (Outcome == 0)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("You have reached the maximum number of trial");
                            this.Close();
                        }
                    }
```

here is my code

in my database i have a U_Name and F_Name, i want to display F_Name

Comment: show your code? what you have done for login?

Comment: just Messagebox.Show("Welcome"); thats it

Comment: What specific column? If you want to display a variable in a message box use             MessageBox.Show("Welcome:" + yourvar);

Comment: Also, is this a web app/desktop app? do you ask your user for their name or is it given?

Comment: Wait, is Bruce Wayne Batman?

Comment: Yes but how you retrieve data from your database?

Comment: no clark kent is superman

Comment: wait i'll update my question be back in a sec

Comment: dont tell me Peter Parker is Spiderman

Comment: hahahaha stop with the jokes Uriel XD i really want to add a welcome message for batman

Comment: Im pretty sure Batman should have no problem to code it by himself, but if he got problems tell him to check [Userprincipal Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx), and no worries, ill keep his identity secret

Comment: now that's a handy link :3 hey just don't tell superman that batman is bruce okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have access to the data (assuming it's in the same row returned by the query), so just pop up another `MessageBox` that uses that value:

```
if (dr.HasRows)
{
    dr.Read();
    int userType = Convert.ToInt32(dr["U_Type"]);

    MessageBox.Show("Welcome, " + dr["F_Name"].ToString())

    if (userType == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
        MDIParent1 settingsForm = new MDIParent1();
        settingsForm.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else if (userType == 2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
        MDIParent2 settingsForm = new MDIParent2();
        settingsForm.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: can't it just be just one pop up message?? i'll try this one. thanks Tim "Again" haha

Comment: Sure - I just put it in a separate `MessageBox` for illustration purposes.  You're welcome, "again". :)

Comment: thanks Tim!!  :D the code worked perfectly hahaha its the second time you helped with my codes THANK YOU!!!

Comment: No problem.  Happy to help.  Remember that the SELECT query you ran will have all the columns from the matching row(s) in that table - so any data you want to grab from that row is available, *as long as the reader is on that row*.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below mentioned code on Login Successful.

```
MessageBox.Show("welcome "+textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: ahmmm that can be, but the username and the real name sometimes are'nt the same, wait i'll update again the question

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Messagebox.Show(Context.User.Identity.Name.ToString());
```

You can use the **split** method like this if you want a part of the user's name like this,

```
Context.User.Identity.Name.ToString().Split('\\')[1]
```

Comment: and what exactly is `Context.User.Identity.Name`?

Comment: @Sayse It's the full name of the user who just log in in the web app.

Comment: I'm not saying its a wrong answer, but your answer provides no details as to what it is or where it comes from

Comment: Context is the alias for HttpContext which is the class which stores all HTTP-specific information about an individual HTTP request, user included.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add User name into public static string.
2. Use it into all child forms.

   ```
   static class Program
   {
      public static string sCurrentUserName;        

      /// <summary>
      /// The main entry point for the application.
      /// </summary>
      [STAThread]
      static void Main()
      {            
          Application.EnableVisualStyles();
          Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
          Application.Run(new Form1());
       }
   }
   ```

In your method:

```
 if (dr.HasRows)
 {
       dr.Read();
       int userType = Convert.ToInt32(dr["U_Type"]);

       if (userType == 1)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
           MDIParent1 settingsForm = new MDIParent1();
           settingsForm.Show();
           this.Hide();
       }
       else if (userType == 2)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
           MDIParent2 settingsForm = new MDIParent2();
           settingsForm.Show();
           this.Hide();
       } 
       Program.sCurrentUserName = dr["F_Name"].ToString(); 
  }
  else
  {
        Program.sCurrentUserName = string.Empty;
        //other code
  }
```

**How to use it in child Forms**:

```
public partial class Form2: Form
{       
    public Form2()
    { 
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Program.sCurrentUserName) == false)
           MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + Program.sCurrentUserName);
         else
         {
             //do something
         }
    }
}
```